# Cannot find module 'npm-cli.js' when running npm (MAC OS Catalina)

Tags: node.js, macos, npm

I installed node via **homebrew** and subsequently **npm** was also installed. But somehow i'm encountering some errors with npm.

So via brew **Node** was installed at: `/usr/local/Cellar/node/15.0.1/bin/node` and **NPM** at: `/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm`.

In the same **npm** **directory** the file `npm-cli.js` is also present but it is still not recognising the file and giving me the following error:

```
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:903
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:900:15)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:745:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:72:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}
```

Following are the PATHS set in .bash_profile:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_271.jdk/Contents/Home
export ANDROID_HOME=/Users/pratt/Library/Android/sdk
export HOMEBREW=/usr/local/Homebrew
export NODE_HOME=/usr/local/Cellar/node/15.0.1
export NPM_PATH=/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm

export PATH=${JAVA_HOME}/bin:
usr/local/bin:
usr/local/sbin:
/usr/bin:
/bin:
/usr/sbin:
/sbin:
${ANDROID_HOME}/emulator:
${ANDROID_HOME}/tools:
${ANDROID_HOME}/tools/bin:
${ANDROID_HOME}/platform-tools:
${HOMEBREW}/bin:
${NODE_HOME}/bin:
${NPM_PATH}/bin
```

If i do `echo $NPM_PATH` it shows the correct directory as set in the Paths: `/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/bin`

I don't know what i'm doing wrong?